# Internal Direct Product without Normality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that if $G$ is a group with normal subgroups $H,K$ such that $G=HK$ and $H\cap K = \langle e \rangle$, then $G\cong H\times K$.

What happens if the normal restriction on $H$ or $K$ or both is removed? Is there still an isomorphism? If not, what fails about the previous isomorphism $f:H\times K\to G$ given by $f(h,k)=hk$? Can conclusions about the structure of $G$ still be made with respect to $H$ and $K$?

Comment: Have you tried looking up "semi-direct products" (for the case where only one of $H$ and $K$ is normal)?

Comment: I've tried reading about them before, the construction seems abstract and I can't really get any intuition behind it. Any advice on that front?

Comment: @MightyTyGuy Continue searching for a source to semidirect product that appeals to you. It is one of the most important constructions in group theory and one cannot really avoid it. Google "Milne groups" and read his notes. Very good, indeed.

Comment: Just to answer a specific part of your question. Being a homomorphism will fail if one or both are not normal. (to see this simply do the proof of that)

Comment: Semidirect products are the most well known example, where exactly one subgroup is not normal. Then there's a version where neither is normal, and we can still say something useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa–Szép_product

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $H$ is normal but $K$ is not normal. Suppose $G = HK$ and $H \cap K = \{ 0 \}$.

It is still the case that every element $g \in G$ can be expressed in the form $ g = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$.

The thing that changes is the multiplication rule. Suppose you want to multiply $g_1 = h_1k_1$ with $g_2 = h_2 k_2$. You get:

$$ g_1 g_2 = h_1 k_1 h_2 k_2 = h_1 (k_1 h_2 k_1^{-1}) k_1 k_2.$$

But since $H$ is a *normal* subgroup, $k_1 h_2 k_1^{-1}$ is also an element of $H$! Let's call this element $h_2^{k_1} = k_1 h_2 k_1^{-1} \in H$. Thus
$$ g_1 g_2 = (h_1 h_2^{k_1}) (k_1 k_2), $$
which now is manifestly written as an element of $H$ multiplied by an element of $K$.

So you can think of $G$ as follows: The elements of $G$ are uniquely specified by pairs $(h,k)$, where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. The multiplication rule is
$$ (h_1, k_1).(h_2, k_2) = (h_1 h_2^{k_1}, k_1 k_2).$$

This construction may seem a little weird at first! So why not look at a few familiar examples to get used to it? For example, suppose $G$ is the symmetry group of the triangle. Suppose $H$ is the normal subgroup consisting of rotational symmetries, $H = \{ 1, r, r^2 \}$ and $K$ is a subgroup generated by a single reflection, $K = \{ 1, \sigma\}$. It is true that $G = HK$ and $H \cap K = \{ 1 \}$. And $\sigma r \sigma^{-1} = r^2$ and $\sigma r^2 \sigma^{-1} = r$. It may be instructive to think about how these general remarks about multiplication in semi-direct products apply to this example.

Comment: If both subgroups are non-normal, are all bets off?

Comment: @Mighty See my comment above.